# How to write a file to the host in advance and then start the Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs, osrm

My task is to deploy a third-party [OSRM service](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend) on [Amazon ECS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc&fargate-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&fargate-blogs.sort-order=desc).

For OSRM docker at startup, you need to transfer a file containing geodata.

The problem is that Amazon ECS Fargate does not provide access to the host file system and does not provide the ability to attach files and folders during container deployments.

Therefore, I would like to create an intermediate image that, when building, saved the file with geodata, and when starting the container, it would use it when defining volumes.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: you can create container that writes something to filesystem but you need access to filesystem anyway. So, no, you must have some level of access to filesystem even if it's `/tmp`

Comment: If by that you mean you need two containers to start, one inside the other, you definitely can do that. But docker doesn't recommend it (unless developing Docker itself). Can't you start the file in the container? Because if you can use a container to write the file, why not use only that one?

Comment: I tried to improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple.

For this Dockerfile, I created an image on my local machine and hosted it on DockerHub:

```
FROM osrm/osrm-backend:latest
COPY data /data
ENTRYPOINT ["osrm-routed","--algorithm","mld","/data/andorra-latest.osm.pbf"]
```

After that, without any settings and volumes, I launched this image in AWS ECS

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, Amazon ECS is a plain container orchestrator and does not implement docker swarm, so things like docker configs are off the cards.

However, you should be able to do something like this :-

```
ID=$(docker create --name my-osrm osrm-base-image)
docker cp ./file.ext $ID:/path/in/container
docker start $ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can I save the new `ID` image in DockerHub?

Comment: If you have the capability of saving images in a registy then it would probably be better to just use a Dockerfile to make a derived image with the config file embedded. But, `docker container commit` may be able to do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the base container stores data in a folder bound to the volume in which the input file is placed. Accordingly, `docker commit` ignores the generated data. Could you please suggest how I can use a Dockerfile to make a derived image with the config file embedded? I would not want to change the base image dockerfile.

Comment: When you place files in a image, and then create a container, when the volume is created it will auto populate with the contents of the underlying folder (by default - this behaviour can be altered).